# Mounting Office365 Remotely - Jumping through hoops

Tags: windows, powershell, internet-explorer, office365

I've managed to correctly map the user's specific drive, but when I attempt to actually *use* it, I get the following error:

```
PS J:\> echo "test" > test.txt
out-file : Access Denied. Before opening files in this location, you must first add the web site to your trusted sites
list, browse to the web site, and select the option to login automatically.
At line:1 char:1
+ echo "test" > test.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], IOException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
```

Now, I can add the website to the trusted sites list via powershell easily (registry), but what I can't figure out how to do is to remotely select the option to login automatically. I need to do this to 1000's of workstations and would *really* like to avoid sending end-users information on how to sign in.

Microsoft's information on how to deal with this is here [(LINK)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2616712/how-to-configure-and-to-troubleshoot-mapped-network-drives-that-connect-to-sharepoint-online-sites-in-office-365). They require you to click the "Keep me signed in" checkbox to make this work. I'd like to find a way to make it work without this.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't, they have to check that checkbox for "Keep me signed in".  We deal with this each day from time to time, with user's Network Locations not letting them access them.  We log off/on, make sure to check the checkbox, and things work again.

Comment: Seems like this the case - I'll hold out for a few more days to see if anyone gets creative. Thank you,